# Mobile Navigation Location

Tags: mobile, navigation, design-patterns

I've been toying around with an idea lately. It seems to me that access to a mobile navigation positioned at the top of the screen (at least on a mobile device) might be bad UX.

With phone's reaching the upwards of 6 inches, navigation for the site is moving further and further away from the user. Would it not be a better user experience to have the menu located at the bottom of the screen, closer to the users thumbs?

Comment: How did the test subjects react to the placement?

Comment: At this point it's still just an idea. Haven't moved into user testing yet. But I'm defiantly planning on doing this here soon.

Answer (score 3):

1. Depends on how frequent the user is going to use the navigation
2. Imagine scrolling the page down, then you tend to tap frequently near the bottom and drag to the top. Here the user could accidentally tap on the navigation if it is placed at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile navigation is a very tough task one face during Mobile App Design. 
Now a days people using side drawer to place menus in mobile device which has less important. But if you have menu which are highly important you can place down (But not more than four or I say three). As you see in facebook app. Puting it upward is really a bad UX. Or you can refer image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For larger (taller) phones, speaking from personal experience, I tend to use my dominant hand holding the phone keeping my thumb near the top but not able to reach across the screen completely. The expandable menu buttons on the top are actually very convenient for me. I'd suggest testing menu locations with a small focus group to start.

Comment: I'd also suggest you think about whether the intent of the UX is to be a one-hand or two-hand experience.  Based on your design intent, this can influence the layout of the mobile navigation.